# C# Winform read timestamp from text of file

Tags: c#, winforms

I am needing to read a timestamp out of the file and then look back over the last 30 minutes to see if the keyword "CM failed" is displayed. This is a log file being constantly updated even when the application is running. Any ideas? The code provided below does look back over the last 30 but I am not sure of exactly what time it's looking at.

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
//fake file which is opened using Notepad++
string temp = @"C:\Temp\efilelog.txt"; 

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string str = File.ReadAllText(temp);

     Regex reg = new Regex("CM failed" + DateTime.Now.Subtract(ts));

     Match mat = reg.Match(str);

     // Get the creation time of a well-known directory.
     //DateTime dt = File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
     //Console.WriteLine("The last write time for this file was {0}.", dt, ts);

     if (mat.Success)
     {
         //send email which I already have functional
     }

     this.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse last failed time from file, and check if that date was within last 30 minutes. Assume you are writing failed time like this:

```
using (var writer = File.AppendText("efilelog.txt"))            
    writer.WriteLine("CM failed {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

Then you will need following query and regular expression to get last failure time:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("CM failed(?<time>.+)");
var lastFailTime = File.ReadLines("efilelog.txt")
                       .Select(line => regex.Match(line))
                       .Where(m => m.Success) // take only matched lines
                       .Select(m => DateTime.Parse(m.Groups["time"].Value))
                       .DefaultIfEmpty() // DateTime.Min if no failures
                       .Max();
```

Then check if fail was within 30 minutes:

```
TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
if (span > DateTime.Now - lastFailTime)
    // alert
```

---

According to your new requirements, you should use following regular expression:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<time>.+(AM|PM)).*CM failed");
```

Comment: This is what the string looks like in the logfile: 6/24/2013 6:36:25 AM 0 Exception in ProcessRecordFilingRequest: DexFlow.Framework.DXException: Document storage in CM failed.

Comment: You can tune regex pattern, if actual format differs from your current format. Or use `DateTime.ParseExact`

Comment: this is not returning anything where it contains the word. Am I missing something?

Comment: @RaymondBeyrle you are missing DateTime parsing

Comment: I am not very good with this parsing thing. I tried multiple routes yesterday but the only date I got was 1/1/0001. Also, does this write to the file because I cannot allow that to happen as this log file is being constantly updated. In turn, will this process lock the file when it is open? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @RaymondBeyrle can add sample of file (several lines with at least one *CM failed* line)?

Comment: 6/25/2013 8:08:48 AM 3143326 Matched Console node eFile_In
6/25/2013 8:08:48 AM 3143326 Created parcel 13060439
6/25/2013 8:08:48 AM 0 Exception in ProcessRecordFilingRequest: DexFlow.Framework.DXException: Document storage in CM failed. Please contact your system administrator.
6/25/2013 8:08:48 AM 3143326 Case number = 
6/25/2013 8:08:48 AM 0 GetCaseISN for 
6/25/2013 8:08:48 AM 0 Found 0 cases

Comment: @RaymondBeyrle there is no date time in `Document storage in CM failed` line. What are you trying to parse?

Comment: I am trying to look at the timestamp which is the precursor of each line in the log file. Can that not be read?

Comment: @RaymondBeyrle updated. And for future - if you are trying to parse some data, then provide sample of this data in question

Comment: I thought I posted it yesterday but I guess I deleted it. My apologies. Thank you for the assist!

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking what your code does. It is doing an existent check for CM FAILED + a ToString() default string conversion of your datetime object with no space between CM FAILED and it.

Is that your intention?